# Angular (v2) Extended Family Component Communication (without parent or external service)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-components

I need a very easy-to-understand solution to achieve *extended family* (i.e., Uncle to Nephew, Niece to Aunt, self to cousin) communication between components/directives without a common parent/ancestor, external service, or `ngModel`.

As an illustration (though the code is overwhelming), Angular Material 2 uses this example for an [autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/component/autocomplete):

```html
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="State" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
      {{ state }}
    </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

The magic pieces being the `[mdAutocomplete]="auto"` on the `mdInput` directive input, and the practically inversed `#auto="mdAutocomplete"` on the `md-autocomplete` component.

They have an uncle-to-nephew communication relationship and vice versa with no concern of a common ancestor component, `ngModel`, or external service that I'm aware of; but, PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong.

So how do I pull this type of two way communication off as in the example above?

By the way, this was helpful, but only a one-way example: [passing data between siblings Angular2 using observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649825/passing-data-between-siblings-angular2-using-observables)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `@Input` decorator to bind the variable of the parent componet to the child.

Other way is to use `@Output` decorator to return the variable to the parent component.

```
@Input() variable:any;
@Output() variableChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Comment: @Roman_C For many cases that works great, but I need something that doesn't depend on a parent.